# What is the main window Qmmp keyboard shortcut?

Tags: qmmp

I want to access the volume window by keyboard in Qmmp is there is any keyboard shortcut for it or any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get the "diamond" in the other answer. Just for clarity, here's the settings which I got through right click anywhere in Qmmp.

[image]

Comment: I forget about that question. Yes I found the solution but I forget to answer it here. The zero key is used to increase the volume while 9 number key will decrease the volume. Just like @somethis has shared the answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Nice, thank you. Worked well for me on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS Bionic.

Answer (score 1):

The settings for the shortcuts can be accessed through :

```
Click on diamond right beside qmmp --> Select "settings" --> Shortcuts
```

Comment: I am unable to up vote the answer as I don't have enough reputation. Thanks for the answer mate.

Comment: No problem. Thanks @Haziq